# If a boy tries to walk on a circular disc , the disc rotates but the boy remains stationary. Why it violets the law of cons. of angular momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum

Suppose a boy tries to walk on a circular disc of mass = m, radius = r, with a velocity = v. As it is an isolated system, the center of mass of the system will not change, that means boy will not have any actual velocity with respect to an inertial frame of reference.
The disc will rotate(due to static friction between feet and the floor) at an angular speed of v/r.
As it is an isolated system the total angular momentum has to be conserved. The total angular momentum in the starting was zero. But after the movement has started, its net angular momentum will be $L = mr^2v/2r$. As the boy has no velocity in the inertial frame, its angular momentum will be zero.
But it is an contradiction as net angular momentum must be zero even after the movement.
where am i wrong?

Comment: What makes you think the boy remains stationary with respect to an inertial reference frame? Note that as the disc begins to spin, the disc must exert a force *inward* on the boy to keep him going in a circle.  Thus, there is a net force *on* the disk as well, which is counteracted by a force on the pivot of the disk, exerted by the ground.  The system is not isolated!  In addition, importantly, at the moment the boy begins to walk, he exerts a force on the disc, and so it exerts a force on him, and so he *has* to accelerate and hence start moving!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the disk is on a friction-less axle at its center, when the boy starts to walk, he will exert a backward force on the disk, and it will exert a forward force on him. He will move and gain angular momentum.  If he is to continue walking around the rim, the disk will also need to exert a centripetal force on him. The backward force on the disk will give it angular momentum, but a force from the axle will prevent the disk from gaining linear momentum.